# Python - Running code simultaneously (TTS and print functions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

How can I simultaneously run the following code OR run the TTS function after returning the text?

CODE:

```
def main(q):
    # CODE BEFORE THIS. 
    # TTS IS JUST A SIMPLE TEXT TO SPEECH FUNCTION
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
    response = 'BOT: '+ response

    # TTS
    # SIMULTANEOUSLY RUN BELOW
    if(responsetts!=None):
        tts(responsetts)
    else:
        tts(response)
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
       query=input('U: ')
       print(main(query))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution in case you want your `tts` function to run after the response was printed would be, to just let `main` print out response before calling `tts`. But for more flexibility and better responsiveness of your prompt you can use a separate thread for your `tts` call.

The threading module offers a `Timer`, which is a subclass of `Thread`. `Timer` has an `interval` parameter for adding a sleep before the target function gets executed. You could use this to add a delay if you want, or just use `Thread` if you don't need this feature. I use `espeak` in my example instead of tts:

```
import time
import random
import subprocess
from threading import Timer
from functools import partial


def _espeak(msg):
    # Speak slowly in a female english voice
    cmd = ["espeak", '-s130', '-ven+f5', msg]
    subprocess.run(cmd)


def _vocalize(response, responsetts=None, interval=0):
    # "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or
    # is not, never the equality operators." -PEP 8
    if responsetts is not None:
        response = responsetts
    Timer(interval=interval, function=_espeak, args=(response,)).start()


def _get_response(q):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
    response = '42'
    response = 'BOT: '+ response
    return response


def _handle_query(q):
    response = _get_response(q)
    print(response)
    _vocalize(response, interval=0)


def main():
    prompt = partial(input, 'U: ')
    # alternative to using partial: iter(lambda: input('U: '), 'q')
    for query in iter(prompt, 'q'): # quits on input 'q'
        _handle_query(query)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```